# Agrupar documentos con _id único y sumar los valores de un array cuyos _id también se repitan, MongoDB, NodeJS, mongoose, agregate, $group

Tags: array, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

tengo los siguientes registros en MongoDB

```
{
  sucursal: 1
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 50
    }
  ]
},
{
  sucursal: 2
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 30
    },
    {
      producto: 2,
      kilos: 50
    }
  ]
},
{
  sucursal: 1
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 50
    },
    {
      producto: 2,
      kilos: 40
    }
  ]
}
```

Y me gustaría que me devolviera los siguientes datos:

```
{
  sucursal: 1
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 100
    },
    {
      producto: 2,
      kilos: 40
    }
  ]
},
{
  sucursal: 2
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 30
    },
    {
      producto: 2,
      kilos: 50
    }
  ]
}
```

Estoy trabajando con mongoose y nodeJs, estoy usando aggregate con $group y $unwind pero no me da los resultados esperados y me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal, me gustaría agrupar todas las sucursales de modo que ninguna de repita y poner en un arreglo todos los productos que contengan las sucursales que se repitan y a su vez juntar los productos repetidos en un único objeto sumando los campos con valores numéricos.

Primero los agrupo como quiero con el siguiente código:

```
const ordenesTotal = await OrdCompCli.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {fechaEntrega: new Date(fecha), estado: {$gt : 0, $lt : 5}}
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$productos"
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$sucursal",
          productos: {
            $addToSet: {
              producto: "$productos.producto",
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          sucursal: "$_id",
          productos: 1
        },
      },
    ])
```

Lo cual me devuelvo esto y eso esta bien es justo como lo espero:

```
{
  sucursal: 1
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1
    },
    {
      producto: 2
    }
  ]
},
{
  sucursal: 2
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1
    },
    {
      producto: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Ahora agregare el $sum al $addToSet para sumar los campos:

```
$group: {
  _id: "$sucursal",
  productos: {
    $addToSet: {
      producto: "$productos.producto",
      totalKilos: {
        $sum: "$productos.kilos"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pero cuando agrego el campo para realizar la suma ($sum) obtengo esto:

```
{
  sucursal: 1
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 50
    },
    {
      producto: 2,
      kilos: 40
    },
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 50
    },
  ]
},
{
  sucursal: 2
  productos: [
    {
      producto: 1,
      kilos: 30
    },
    {
      producto: 2,
      kilos: 50
    }
  ]
}
```

Como pueden ver no me está sumando los campos, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias por su tiempo, quedo pendiente si puedo aportar más información para resolver esto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así (Explicación con comentarios dentro del código):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { //Divides el array de productos
    $unwind: "$productos"
  },
  { //Agrupas los elementos por sucursal y por producto (sumando sus kilos)
    $group: {
      _id: {
        sucursal: "$sucursal",
        producto: "$productos.producto"
      },
      kilos: {
        $sum: "$productos.kilos"
      }
    }
  },
  { //Luego deshechas el _id y regeneras las propiedades como las quieres
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      sucursal: "$_id.sucursal",
      producto: "$_id.producto",
      kilos: 1
    }
  },
  { //Una vez ya tengas producto/sucursal sumado, agrupas los productos que pertenecen a la misma sucursal
    $group: {
      _id: "$sucursal",
      productos: {
        $push: {
          producto: "$producto",
          kilos: "$kilos"
        },            
      }
    }
  },
  { //Te deshaces de nuevo del _id y lo renombras a "sucursal"
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      sucursal: "$_id",
      productos: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de prueba en mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/5nq8lpZw2iX

Comment: Maestro muchisimas gracias funciono a la perfección, llevaba días peleando con esto, veo que la respuesta correcta esta bastante alejado de lo que pretendía hacer, me falta mucho por aprender, muchas gracias por compartir tu conocimiento